# Why is a m x n matrix representation with a row of zeroes linearly independent? (in this case)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Hope someone can clear up this small question for me: I had to show that a set of vectors (in my case polynomials) is linearly independent, so i calculated a system of equations with gauss elimination and came up with the augmented matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 &|0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 &|0\\
0 & 0 & 1 &|0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & |0\\
\end{bmatrix}$

I can see that $x_1=x_2=x_3=0$, which shows us that the set of vectors is linearly independent. (which is the answer to the question). But, what i don't understand is that if i look at it in another way we have 3 linearly independent rows and 1 linearly dependent row (the row with zeros, so the zero vector, right?). And that must mean that the set of vectors is linearly dependent. (because, for a set of vectors to be independent, all vectors contained in the set have to be linearly independent, right?)

Can someone explain why i'm thinking wrong here? (must be i forgot something or just am not thinking clearly). Ok thanks!

Comment: Matrices aren't linearly dependent, *vectors* are (actually we can impose a linear dependency property on matrices but not in this context). Can you state what you mean by the fact that the matrix is linearly independent? Because its columns are, but its rows aren't.

Comment: Yes i formulated it a bit wrong i guess, maybe like "Why is the m x n matrix representation of a system of linear equations with a row of zeroes linearly independent?". And i'm clearly confused: how can the matrix representation of the vectors be linearly indepent, while the matrix contains a row with zeros. So the way i see it is, we have 3 linearly independent vectors and 1 linearly dependent vector (because we got a row with zeros).

Comment: A set of vectors which includes a zero vectors is automatically linearly dependent. (Linear (in)dependence is a characteristic of sets of vectors.)

Comment: "how can the matrix representation of the vectors be linearly indepent"?  It can't.  The phrase "this matrix is/isn't linearly independent" is not a meaningful sentence in our context.

Comment: So when you've got a row with zeros in your "matrix representation of a set with vectors" it doesn't mean that the set contains the zero vector?

Comment: It depends how exactly the matrix is used to represent vectors.  In your context, the vectors correspond to the **columns** of the matrix, not the rows. So, the fact that the rows are linearly dependent does not tell us that the vectors are linearly dependent.

Comment: Yes, i understand that, it was more that i was a bit confused about the fact that it wasn't a square matrix (so the row with zeros wouldn't be there).

Comment: In square matrices, things become a lot clearer: in that case, a matrix cannot be *invertible* if it contains a row of zeroes, or if its rows are linearly dependent, or if its columns are linearly dependent.